# Checking the contraction of a given function

Tags: numerical-methods

Let$$\Phi:R^2\to R^2$$ be defined as following
$$\Phi(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{\sin(x)}{4}+y , 1+\sin(y)+x)^T$$
And we need to check if it is contraction with respect to Norm infinity and norm 2!
I have got solution but i actually it is not understandable! I appreciate your help!

For norm infinity it is used the infinity norm of the jacobian of the matrix $||D\Phi(x,y)||_\infty<1$ (not sure if this is right)  and for 2 norm it is used the contraction condition $$
||\Phi (x_1,y_1)-\Phi(x_2,y_2)||_2\leq L||(x_-x_2),(y_1-y_2)||_2$$ $$L<1$$ where L is Lipschitz constant which should be less than one. I am also wondering if we can use the same condition to show that it is not contraction for $||.||_\infty$

Comment: You need to provide more information so we can write an answer which will be useful to you. It would be useful to have a summary of the suggested solution highlighting you current problems.

Comment: @Carl Christian I wrote what have been used in the solution I have got.

Answer (score 1):

We need to investigate if there exists constant $\lambda \in [1,1)$ such that
$$
\forall p_1, p_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2 \: : \: \|\Phi(p_1) - \Phi(p_2)\|_2 \leq \lambda \|p_1-p_2\|_2$$
and a constant $\mu \in [0,1)$
$$
\forall p_1, p_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2 \: : \: \|\Phi(p_1) - \Phi(p_2)\|_\infty \leq \mu \|p_1-p_2\|_\infty$$

Let therefore $p_1 = (x_1,y_1)$ and $p_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ be two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We must control the difference between $\Phi(p_1)$ and $\Phi(p_2)$. When $n=1$ we can typically apply the mean value theorem. In higher dimensions a rewrite it is required:

Define the auxiliary function $g : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$ g(t) = \Phi(tp_2+(1-t)p_1).$$
By the chain rule, this function is differentiable and the derivative is
$$ g'(t) = D\Phi(tp_2+(1-t)p_1)\cdot(p_2-p_1) dt.$$
Here $D\Phi$ denotes the Jacobian of $\Phi$ and $\cdot$ is the Euclidian inner product. Moreover $g(0)=\Phi(p_1)$ and $g(1) = \Phi(p_2)$. It follows that
$$ \Phi(p_2) - \Phi(p_1) = g(1) - g(0) = \int_0^1 g'(t) dt = \int_{0}^1 D\Phi(tp_2+(1-t)p_1)\cdot(p_2-p_1) dt.$$
This implies
$$ \| \Phi(p_2) - \Phi(p_1) \| \leq \int_{0}^1 \| D\Phi(tp_2+(1-t)p_1) \| \cdot \|(p_2-p_1) \|dt. $$
regardless of the choice of norm. We conclude that it is worthwhile to investigate the size of 
$$ C_2 = \int_{0}^1 \| D\Phi(tp_2+(1-t)p_1) \|_2 dt$$
as well as
$$ C_\infty = \int_{0}^1 \| D\Phi(tp_2+(1-t)p_1) \|_\infty dt$$
Now, if the Jacobians could be bounded by a number strictly less than unity, we would be done. With $p = (x,y)$ we have
$$  D\Phi(p) = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{4} \cos(x) & 1 \\ 1 & \cos(y) \end{bmatrix}. $$
The Jacobian is real and symmetric, so the 2-norm is determined by the eigenvalues. By Gershgorin's circle theorem, it follows that
$$ \|D\Phi(p)\|_2 \leq 1.$$
By direct definition of the infinity norm we have
$$ \|D\Phi(p)\|_\infty \leq 1.$$
This certainly does not preclude the possibility that $\Phi$ is a contractive mapping, but more work is required.

To that end, we return to the expression for $D\Phi(p)$. For simplicity we consider $2 D\Phi(p)$. The characteristic polynomial of $2 D\Phi(p)$ is
$$ p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{1}{4} \cos(x) + \cos(y) \right)\lambda + \left(\frac{1}{4}\cos(x)\cos(y)-1\right)$$
The pressing issue is bound the eigenvalues away from $\pm 2$. By the triangle inequality a root $\lambda$ must necessarily satisfy
$$ |\lambda|^2 \leq \frac{5}{4} |\lambda| + \frac{5}{4}.$$
This puts a hard limit on the size of $|\lambda|$, specifically
$$|\lambda| \leq \frac{5 + \sqrt{105}}{4} < 2.$$
We can in fact conclude that $\Phi$ is a contractive mapping with respect to the $2$-norm.

Currently, I have no good ideas about the case of the infinity norm.

---

UPDATE: Let us explore what can be done by direct calculation with $\Phi$. We have
$$ \Phi(p_2) - \Phi(p_1) = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{4} \left(\sin(x_2) - \sin(x_1)\right) + y_2 - y_1 \\ x_2-x_1 + \sin(y_2) - \sin(y_1) \end{bmatrix} $$
The following inequality should be understod in the componentwise sense:
$$|\Phi(p_2) - \Phi(p_1)| \leq \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{4}|x_2 - x_1| + |y_2-y_1| \\ |x_2 - x_1| + |y_2 - y_1| \end{bmatrix}$$
It follows
$$ \|\Phi(p_2) - \Phi(p_1)\|_\infty \leq \|p_2-p_1\|_\infty $$
Moreover, exploring the choice of $x_1=y_1=h$ and $x_2=y_2=2h$ and allowing $h$ to tend to zero will reveal that this is the best possible bound. We conclude that $\Phi$ is not a contraction with respect to the infinity norm.

Comment: @ Carl Christian Actually the norm infinity is not less than one we we take that tha maximum value of trig function is one the infinity norm in our case will be 1 and so we concluded that it is not a contraction...this is what i have in my solution !

Comment: @FarhanOmar: I have added information about the case of the infinity norm. Let me know if is clear or not.